# Problemas para hacer web scrapping con puppeteer y javascript

Tags: javascript, web, puppeteer

hace poco comenze a aprender sobre puppeteer para hacer scrapping de paginas web, para practicar he decidido intentar con la pokedex en la pagina: https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/.
De esta quiero sacar nombre del pokemon y su numero de id (Anexo imagen)
[![][1]][1]

Ese es el codigo resultante luego de intentarlo

```js
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/');
    await page.waitForSelector("h5");
    await page.waitFor(3000);
    const pokemon = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const pokes1 = document.querySelectorAll('h5');
    const id = document.querySelectorAll('p.id');
    const valor = {};
    for (let poke1 of pokes1) {
        valor.push(poke1.textContent);
    }
    return valor;
    })
    console.log (pokemon);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Pasa que al ejecutarlo con cmd me sale esto y no se que hacer para solucionarlo
[![][2]][2]

Espero y me pueden ayudar porque no se que hacer la verdad, abrazos!

```html
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1139]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\susan>node index2.js
waitFor is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. See https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6214 for details and how to migrate your code.
(node:9680) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: valor.push is not a function
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:6:15
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\Users\susan\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:217:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\Users\susan\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:106:16)
    at async C:\Users\susan\index2.js:8:21
(node:9680) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9680) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Por favor, podrías quitar la imagen y poner el error como texto?

Comment: Claro @braver lo acabo de editar, gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: valor.push is not a function

Este error significa que el atributo `push` de `valor` no es una función. Esto
pasa porque al acceder a un atributo que no fue definido en un objeto de Javascript,
la expresión se evalua en `undefined`.

Si quieres usar una lista en la que le puedas "meter" objetos con push debes
usar [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Por ejemplo:

```
const valor = []; // en vez de `{}`

for (let poke1 of pokes1) {
    valor.push(poke1.textContent);
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @braver, me salvaste